# Why doesn't event.relatedTarget work with focusin/focusout event in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, dom, event-handling, focus

I need to find the previously focused item in my focusin function. Here is an example code:

```
$('#id').on('focusin', function(event) {
  //console.log(event.relatedTarget.nodeName);    //doesn't work
}
```

I've done some research and while I've seen some people saying in posts that this only works with mouse events like mousedown etc., I've come across a few articles from reputable sources that have me believing this should work.

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.relatedTarget Here Firefox **specifically** mentions how event.relatedTarget returns "which EventTarget is losing focus" in the 'focusin' event.
   *Firefox is the browser I am using for this.*
2. http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-FocusEvent at this bookmark you can see that every FocusEvent has a readonly attribute called related target.
3. http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-focusIn Here they specifically state as well that the 'FocusEvent' has a property called 'relatedTarget' which is "event target losing focus (if any)."

So then what am I doing wrong here? It must be some kind of dumb syntax mistake or something. I cannot find the nodeName of event.relatedTarget.

Update: I can get it to work in IE using, but this won't work in Firefox???

```
 $("#id").on('focusin', function(event) {
   $('#textbox').text(event.relatedTarget.nodeName);
 }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although MDN mentions relatedTarget for the `focusin` /`focusout` events, unfortunately, no version of FireFox actually supports those two events. jQuery simply emulates them for you but due to lack of native support, you don't get relatedTarget on FF.

See compatibility info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/focusout) or [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html#t09).